# How to build SEG in your personal environment?

Tags: genetics, protein-structure, complexity

I'm trying to implement SEG [(Wootton & Federhen,1993)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/009784859385006X) in my MATLAB and Python environment. From this oriinal article I cannot figure out what I need to build my script. Are there any related article that explains the various steps to build this algorithm (from the mathematical point of view)?

Comment: Your question seems to relate to software rather than biology. You are likely to have more luck in SE Bioinformatics.

Comment: Yes I know that it seems like that. But I do not want anyone to explain me the code. I want to know if any of the users of this blog know the related articles. From a certain point of view it could be related to the biology context since we all have to study and we all can share our experience!

Comment: That paper isn't open access, so many potential helpers (including me) can't read it...